# Smartsheet function is UNPARSEABLE

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

On the Sheet Summary I'm trying  to write a function that will  track Past Due tasks below is the format :

```
=COUNTIF([Is Past Due?]:[Is Past Due?], "Yes")
```

The formula doesn't work as it says "UNPARSEABLE". Below is the Past Due column name

[image: Here is te Past Due column name]

Comment: I'd suggest you post this question to the Smartsheet Community [Formulas and Functions](https://community.smartsheet.com/categories/formulas-and-functions) online support forum, as that's the appropriate place for questions like this that seek help with in-app functionality. (Stack Overflow is a venue for programming-related questions -- i.e., if you're having trouble using the Smartsheet API. Based on the information you've provided, it doesn't sound like you're using the API.) If you are, in fact, using the API to set the formula -- please update your question to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

The UNPARSEABLE error in Smartsheet happens when, the formula has a problem which prevents it from being parsed and interpreted.

Example:

-misspelling
-incomplete operators
-using the wrong case for a column name
-using single quotes instead of double quotes

Maybe, you have to review the syntax of the function COUNTIF, and make sure to use acceptable operators, follow this [link](https://help.smartsheet.com/function/countif) for more information about the function

---Syntax---

**COUNTIF( *range*,*criterion* )**

*range*
— The group of cells to count.

*criterion*
— The value that determines which cells in the range will be counted.

I hope this information can be useful for you.